# I need to change default mail

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 Free testimonial.

Problem is that mail going from order mail id .And I have to change this  with custom mail .

```
public function sendemailAction($to, $templateConfigPath) {
        if(!$to) return;
        $translate=Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        $mailTemplate=Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
        $template=Mage::getStoreConfig($templateConfigPath, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $sendTo=array();
        foreach($to as $recipient) {
            if(is_array($recipient)) {
                $sendTo[]=$recipient;
            }
            else {
                $sendTo[]=array(
                    'email'=>$recipient,
                    'name'=>null
                );  
            }

        }
        foreach ($sendTo as $recipient ) {
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
            ->sendTransactional(
            $template,
            Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),
            $recipient['email'],
            $recipient['name'],
            array('customer_name' =>$this->_getTestimonial()->load($testimonialId)->getName(),
                    'customer_email'  =>$this->_getTestimonial()->load($testimonialId)->getEmail(),
                    'address'         =>$this->_getTestimonial()->load($testimonialId)->getAddress(),
                    'website'         =>$this->_getTestimonial()->load($testimonialId)->getWebsite(),
                    'company'         =>$this->_getTestimonial()->load($testimonialId)->getCompany(),
                    'testimonial'     =>$this->_getTestimonial()->load($testimonialId)->getTestimonial()
                  )
            );
        }
        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
          return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set custom FROM address you have to replace below line in sendTransactional Function

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),
TO >>  $sender = array('name' => 'Customer Name',
               'email' => 'customer@custom.mail');
      sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
```